# Multitouch swipe gesture

Tags: iphone, ui-automation

How can I simulate a two-finger left-to-right swipe within a UITextView in UIAutomation?

I've tried this:

```
var textView = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().textViews()[0];
textView.dragInsideWithOptions({
    touchCount:2,
    startOffset:{x:0.2, y:5.80},
    endOffset:{x:0.8, y:5.80},
    duration:1.5
});
```

But apparently it is not having any effect. Sometimes it looks like it is doing only one finger gesture even I am passing `2` as the touch count.

One concern is: How UIAutomation knows where place the second touch? I am only specifying the start and end of one touch, not two. Is this correct? Maybe this is the origin of my problem?
Also, I have not very clear the coordinates system of objects. Unless I pass very small values  for x, y I usually get warnings: *out of bounds*. Passing coordinates I would usually pass using Objective-C seem to be way large :(

Comment: have ypu set the number of touches to 2?

Comment: I think I did it above ... `touchCount:2` Is this not enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051104/how-to-handle-1-to-3-fingers-swipe-gesture-in-ios

Comment: Above link is for implementing the swipe gesture, which I've already done. I want to implement a test for it using the builtin javascript library in Instruments.app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very late answer...
I met your problem today, in 2015, and I have the chance to have Apple doc for this function. Wasn't the case in 2012 perhaps...

Apple docs says :

> You can use offsets to achieve finer precision in specifying the hitpoint within the rect for the specified element. The offset comprises a pair of x and y values, each ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. These values represent, respectively, relative horizontal and vertical positions within the rect, with {x:0.0, y:0.0} as the top left and {x:1.0, y:1.0} as the bottom right. Thus, {x:0.3, y:0.6} specifies a position just below and to the left of center, and {x:1.0, y:0.5} specifies a position centered vertically at the far right.
>
> This example performs a slow drag within the target element from left edge to right edge, just below the top:
>
> target.dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.0, y:0.1}, endOffset:{x:1.0, y:0.1}, duration:1.5});

So x and y values are relative within the rect you choose.
In your example :

```
startOffset:{x:0.2, y:5.80}
```

You begin the swipe from left in the textview at 20% of its length, and y is 5.80 times beyond the border...

It would better work with values as :

```
startOffset:{x:0.0, y:0.1}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.1}
```

For my part, I made the two-finger left-to-right swipe work with this code :

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().dragInsideWithOptions({touchCount:2, startOffset:{x:0.0, y:0.1}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.1}, duration:1});
```

Comment: better later than never! hehe ;)